# MySQL-query returns all entries except for only one

Tags: java, mysql

I have this Java application that I made and it works using both Java and MySQL. The connection worked and everything's fine. But in the Java application form, I've got 4 buttons and the first button displays the first record from the table in MySQL. I want the second button to display the second record ONLY. but the code I've written shows both second and the rest of the records as well. Please help me it's and important project that I've got to submit soon. Thank you.
Here's what I've written in the source code for the second button:

```
try{
    Connection connection=getConnection();
    stmt=connection.createStatement();
    rs=stmt.executeQuery("Select * from hospital where pno>"+txtpno.getText()+" order by pno limit 2;");
    if(rs.next()){
        txtpno.setText(rs.getString("pno"));
        txtpname.setText(rs.getString("pname"));
        txtgender.setText(rs.getString("gender"));
        txtage.setText(rs.getString("age"));
        txtdname.setText(rs.getString("dname"));
        txtdep.setText(rs.getString("dep"));
    }
}
catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex.toString());
}
finally{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "next()" twice:

```
rs=stmt.executeQuery("Select * from hospital where pno>"+txtpno.getText()+" order by pno limit 2;");
// here the change
if(rs.next() && rs.next()){
    txtpno.setText(rs.getString("pno"));
// ...
```

Comment: @LuluLala if this answer is correct, accept it so the question is closed

Answer (score 0):

just add offset to your sql

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 1, 2 ;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM  tbl LIMIT 2 offset 1;
```

code

```
rs=stmt.executeQuery("Select * from hospital where pno>"+txtpno.getText()+" order by pno limit 2 offset 1;");
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, you should know by know that `rs.next()` "loads" the next row to be fetched data from.
So just call `rs.next()` once to bypass the first row and you're golden.

Also, close your statements and connections in the `finally` block!